# How to solve the issue of Android Studio 3 (3.1 canary) Preview: Cannot import project

Tags: android-studio

I am working on Android Studio 3 Preview at the moment. However, whenever I tried to open an old project it says:

> The project file specified already exists.

I have deleted:

1. Old code/project from hard disk (completely)
2. Removed the project from the project list.

Any tips on this?

[image]

Comment: 3.1 canary or 3.0 beta? If it's the second, AS 3 is in the stable channel noe. If you're trying to use 3.0, go for the stable release and see if that helps

Comment: 3.1 canary @Zoe

Comment: @Ben Did you try: **File->Invalidate Caches/Restart...**  option. Also try text search in your system for the 'project name' file. I personally did not face any such error in Studio 3.1 Canary.

Comment: @ManmeetP Still the same. But thanks anyway.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This needs two steps:

1. You must delete the **.idea** folder under your project. It is a hidden directory. use `ls -a` to find it out.
2. Right click `build.gradle` and choose application. It probably popup a window asking for a program to open it, choose `Android Studio`.

Comment: wow this took me my whole life to find. Is this a bug in Android Studio?

Answer (score 17):

I faced the same problem with 3.1 and .idea folder was also not there. Still it was not working. So instead of doing "Import Project" I did  "Open an existing Android Studio project" and it worked.

Answer (score 5):

I encounter same problem recently when opening existing Android Project,
deleting `.idea` or open directly `build.gradle` through Mac OS Finder work for me

Answer (score 1):

Open the gradle file (select Android Studio if an application picker pops up) and it should bring up the "Import Project" dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Just go to your Project Location Delete All files like .idea, .app etc and Relocate Your Project Location.

Answer (score 0):

From Android Studio on toolbar click File > Close Project, then you will be prompted to select a project to open, click Open and select the build.gradle of the project you want to import.